# Remove unnecessary errors from console log?

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube-api

I have this custom YouTube embed with some neat little gadgets, it works perfectly, but there's one problem. There are many errors in the console such as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getVolume' of undefined
index.html:189 Uncaught TypeError: player.getVolume is not a function
index.html:179 Uncaught TypeError: player.getCurrentTime is not a function
index.html:183 Uncaught TypeError: player.getCurrentTime is not a function
```

I don't know what could be causing these errors, I've tried doing many things with the code such as moving and re-assigning variables and I just can't seem to clear them out, any help?

**CODEPEN:** http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/MwONzK

Comment: `Cannot read property 'getVolume' of undefined` means that `player` is undefined at js line 83. Same happens with the rest, there are no functions inside `player` since it is still undefined. Probably the variable `player` is still empty when you try to access it.

Comment: The player variable can't be empty though, The video loads... so that means that it's been initiated. And I'm loading all other variables below the player

Comment: Since you assign a value into `player` variable inside `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function, when the `setInterval()` functions are fired, `player is still undefined` (js lines 72 and 81). You have to initiate (or call) the intervals into `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`, after create the player into `player` variable.

Comment: Ok! I got the "undefined" errors to go away, But now how would I get the "is not a function" errors to go away? Because it's clearly working... I just can't seem to target why my code isn't recognizing "getVolume" and "getCurrentTime" as functions when they clearly are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `onReady` method from the player to fire into it the intervals, so you will be sure that `player` variable is already defined.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var rangerGo;
    var player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '282',
        width: '502',
        videoId: 'QExOaGT_ids',
        playerVars: {
            'controls': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'iv_load_policy': 3,
            'rel': 0,
        },
        events: {
            onReady: function(){
                setInterval(function() {
                    $("#content").text("video_time: " + player.getCurrentTime().toString().toHHMMSS());
                }, 250);

                rangerGo = setInterval(function() {
                    $("#range").slider("value", player.getCurrentTime());
                    $("#range").slider("option", "max", player.getDuration());
                }, 250);

                setInterval(function() {
                    // VOLUME CONTROLS
                    $("#volume-amount").text("volume: " + player.getVolume() + "%");
                    player.setVolume($("#volume-range").slider("value"));
                }, 1);

                $("#range").slider({
                    range: "min",
                    start: function(event, ui) {
                        player.pauseVideo();
                        clearInterval(rangerGo);
                    },
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        player.seekTo(ui.value, true);
                        player.playVideo();
                        rangerGo = setInterval(function() {
                            $("#range").slider("value", player.getCurrentTime());
                            $("#range").slider("option", "max", player.getDuration());
                        }, 250);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```